# Styling individual letters in word

Tags: css, css-selectors

I' currently trying to Style the word "Siteripe". I'd like each letter to have a different color. As shown on this [page](http://www.mobile.siteripe.com) I'm able to style just the first letter with the lines of CSS code below

```
#namer:first-letter {
  color:#09C;
  font-size:1.1em;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Since there eight(8) letters in the word, how do I style the remaining seven? I did try the styling bellow but it didn't work. Is there a way to Style the letters individually without wrapping each letter using spans.

```
   #namer:(1)-letter {
      color:#09C;
      font-size:1.1em;
      font-weight:bold;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, CSS is **Cascading**. You can style the whole #namer element separately from the first letter - the more specific style will override the more general one.

```
#namer:first-letter {
    color:#09C;
    font-size:1.1em;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#namer {
    color:red;
}
```

**Update:**

[Lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/) allows for styling individual letters. See the comments below for additional information. The info above is for styling the initial character only, and was in answer to the OP's original question before it was edited to make it clearer.

Comment: Dave how do I style the rest of the letterS?

Comment: I thought you wanted to style the rest of the word, not the seven individual letters separately. Apologies. Unfortunately, you'll have to wrap the others in spans and give them separate IDs to style them - there are no pseudo-classes beyond 'first-letter' for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Dz.slick - I've done some more research today, and there's a jQuery plugin which you may want to investigate, called lettering.js. More information here: http://trentwalton.com/2011/01/18/controlling-web-typography/

Comment: This does not style each letter, so it is not answer to the question asked.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela The question was edited *after* I answered, clarifying that each letter required colouring, not the whole word or the first character. The comments above explain this, plus the extra research I did. Lettering.js certainly does allow for per-character styling. See the examples here: https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js

Comment: My point was that it was wrong to accept an answer that does not answer the question in its current form. Such acceptance is misleading to people who find the question and the answer as they are (whatever their history might be).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I've updated my answer to draw attention to the additional information which was added after the OP changed their question.

Comment: This has nothing to do with cascading, or specificity. `#namer` refers to the element with the ID, `#namer:first-letter` refers to a pseudo-element *within* that element, and not the element itself. (You could say that cascading happens in that the color declaration on `#namer:first-letter` overrides what would otherwise have been inherited from `#namer`, but that still has no relation to specificity whatsoever.)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select the entire text using the selector without the indexing

```
#namer:first-letter {
    color:#09C;
    font-size:1.1em;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#namer {
    color:red!important;
}
```

You can then select the first letter using the indexing method above

Comment: I was just testing it out in firebug, i have a habit of adding !important, as it overrides any other css that may be affecting the style. I use it as a quick way to see whether i selected the element i wanted

Comment: To be honest, if you can get away with it, dont use !important, its a kind of last resort thing, but makes testing easy etc.

Answer (score -2):

The pseudo element "first-letter" is self-explanatory, it is intended for the first letter ONLY. Does each of the rest of the letters will have a different style?if not, you might want to wrap each letter within a span tag and assign it a CSS rule.

Now you are able to style the rest of the letters as a whole.
Then in your CSS:

```
#namer:first-letter {
color:#09C;
font-size:1.1em;
font-weight:bold;
}

span {
color:red;
.
.
.
}
```

If you want to style EACH letter you might try wrapping each letter using spans. However, it might visually look like a total mess. 
Note: come up with a better name for your class #LOL

Comment: It looks a LOT cleaner if you dont use inline styling, you use n-th child css selector, and you create your own span and call it s.