# Style specific letter?

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to style letters based on what letter it is. So K:s sholud have one color, I:s one etc. What's the cleanest way to to this? Are there any selectors for it? (initially I'm going to do it with a greasemonkeyscript)

Comment: looks like a dub of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918349/styling-individual-letters-in-word

Comment: This site gonna make me feel like I'm on drugs or something. All these different colors.

Comment: No, there isn't a CSS selector for this. The only selector that affects individual letters is `:first-letter`, and that isn't what you're looking for. You'll have to use a bit of Javascript to achieve this.

Answer (score 5):

Javascript, <s>untested</s> fixed:

```
yourstring.replace(/([kK])/g, "<span class='styled'>$1</span>");
```

---

Working example:

```
<html><head></head><body>

<div id='target'>
    some text with little ks and big Ks and a few more for good measure kK7k9Kii
</div>
</body></html>


<script type='text/javascript'>    
target = document.getElementById('target');

target.innerHTML = target.innerHTML.replace(/([kK])/g, "<span style='color:red'>$1</span>");

</script>
```

---

MDN's `.replace()` documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the plugin [lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jquery very easily as below :

Html :

```
<p class="menu">Home k edit k etc</p>
```

Css :

```
span.sp {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

Javascript/Jquery:

```
$('p.menu').html(function(i,el) {
    return el.replace(/\k/g, '<span class="sp">k</span>');
});
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/butani_vijay010/ymE6y/23/) Link